# Code checkout related questions on Git

Tags: git, github

Suppose I've a file "A.java" committed on 01.01.2016 and another file named "B.java" committed on 05.01.2016.

Now I'm performing a code checkout from Git on 10.01.2016, then both the files are getting downloaded on 10.01.2016.

My requirement is to get the full content of the file downloaded on the specific dates as they are being committed. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want `A.java` from `01.01.2016` and `B.java` from `05.01.2016`, is that right?  May we ask why you want to do this (and there may be a better way to achieve what you want) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well if 1/1/2016 and 5/1/2016 were the dates of the last commits of the respective files, those are the instances you will get by default, so I'll assume there have been commits to those files since then. To get the contents of a file (say, A.java) from a specific commit (say, 12345), you will want to do `git checkout 12345 A.java`.

Comment: there is a commit for a project version (say version 1.1) on 10.03.2016 and another commit for the version (say version 1.2). Now when i'm performing codebase checkout for the projects latest version for 1.2, the whole project is getting downloaded on the current date (say 18.04.2016). So if some 'lib' files getting changed or not, those can't be uniquely identified; rather the whole content is found to be different till i now manually where the differentiation lies. I want to know any way to identify uniquely which files are changed from one version to other?